# xampp not working, and error appears when I try to start my server

Tags: php, html, mysql, xampp

```
Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
11:58:07  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
11:58:07  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
11:58:07  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
11:58:07  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
11:58:07  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
11:58:07  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums
```

I can't start the server, the errors above appear when I try to

Comment: Have you tried editing the port Apache listens on in your config file? Try making it 8080 rather than 80.

Answer (score 1):

Open **XAMPP Control Panel** and select **Config** under Apache. Select your *httpd.conf* and locate the following line.

```
# Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
# ports, instead of the default. See also the <VirtualHost>
# directive.
#
# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
#
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80 
Listen **xx**
```

Where you see **xx** change this to something like **8080** if it currently states **81**. Port 81 is commonly used by a few applications, so I tend to always change to 8080 by default, but your network may be different. You may use `netstat` to see what ports may be available to you.

Restart **XAMPP** entirely as Apache is very fussy, then try starting Apache again.

Answer (score 1):

Apache by default use 80 port if that port is alrady occupied by some other programs may lead to this issue. Following steps to resolve this :

**Step 1** - From the XAMPP Control Panel, under Apache, click the Config button, and select the Apache (httpd.conf).

Inside the httpd.conf file, somehow I found a line that says:

Listen 80

And change the 80 into any number / port you want. In my scenario I’m using port 8080.

Listen 8080

Still from the httpd.conf file, I found another line that says:

ServerName localhost:80

Change 80 to 8080.

ServerName localhost:8080

Save httpd.conf file after done with changes

**Step 2** - From the XAMPP Control Panel, under Apache, click the Config button again, but this time select the Apache (httpd-ssl.conf). Inside the httpd-ssl.conf file, find line that says

Listen 443

And change the 443 into any number / port you want. I’ll using 4433 as the new port number.

Listen 4433

Still from the httpd-ssl.conf file, find another line that says

ServerName localhost:443

And change 443 to 4433.

ServerName localhost:4433

Save httpd-ssl.conf files after done with changes

**P.S :**  Restart the Apache service.

Comment: For more details -> 
https://www.webucator.com/blog/2016/05/fixing-a-blocked-port-in-xampp/